# Laravel: get percentage of each values in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, percentage

I have a two array variables with numbers. I need a third one  who will also be an array but with percentage of first two arrays. For example:

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => 256
  1 => 312
  2 => 114
]

array:15 [▼
      0 => 100
      1 => 211
      2 => 12
    ]
```

so I need a variable to look like this:

```
array:15 [▼
          0 => 39.0
          1 => 67.6
          2 => 10.5
        ]
```

The first two variables I get like this:

```
$settlements = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
  ->withCount('members')
  ->where('reon_id', '1')
  ->get();

foreach ($settlements as $settlement) {
  $sett[] = $settlement->members->count();
}

$sett_members = Settlement::where('town_id', Auth::user()->town_id)
  ->withCount('members')
  ->where('reon_id', '1')
  ->get();

foreach ($sett_members as $sett_member) {
  $sett_m[] = $sett_member->members->where('cipher_id', '0')->count();
}
```

but when I try to calculate percentage like this:

```
$percentage = round(($sett_m / $sett) * 100,1);
```

it shows error **Unsupported operand types**

Comment: You can't do mathematical operation directly with two arrays you have to do with array elements.

Comment: How to separate elements from array to be able to do mathematical operation?

Comment: could you please explain your calculation??

Comment: I've added my answer take a moment to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `loop` through your array, do `calculation` with `same index` element and store in a `new` array.

```
$percentage = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($sett_m);$i++) {
    if($sett[$i]!=0){
    $percentage[$i] = round(($sett_m[$i] / $sett[$i]) * 100, 1);
   }
}

print_r($percentage);
```

Comment: How to avoid **Division by zero Error** because I have some elements with 0?

Comment: make a check if dividend element is zero or not, check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation of array operators available in php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php,

you can only use following operators in array,

1. Union
2. Equality
3. Identity
4. Inequality
5. Non-Identity

for your case, you can do it like,

if you have arrays like `$arr1` and `$arr2` then,

```
$arr1 = array(0 => 256, 1 => 312,2 => 114);

$arr2 =  array(0 => 100,1 => 211,2 => 12);

$calculator = function($first, $second) { 

                    if($second == 0)
                         return 0;
                    else 
                         return round($first/$second * 100,2); 
               };

$percentage = array_map($calculator, $arr2, $arr1);
```

Here you will get `$percentage` array as the desired result.

Comment: What is $arr2? Is that $second?

Comment: $arr1 is the your first array and arr2 is  your second array

Comment: I've updated my answer so you can understand easily. Any way you understand how it works. I'm glad